# Render points on a map

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to plot geo coordinates on a pictureBox but what I'm doing doesn't appear to be working. I can't really figure out why either. I use code to determine the plot points that correlate between the dimension of the image and the actual geo coordinates. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
private void renderMap(Points p)
{
  SizeF dimensions = pictureBox1.Image.PhysicalDimension;
  float width = dimensions.Width;
  float height = dimensions.Height;
  PictureBox image = this.pictureBox1;
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image.Image);

  while (p is not null)
  {
    float x, y;
    x = float.Parse(p.lon) * width / (width - height);
    y = float.Parse(p.lat) * height / (0 - height);

    //Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
    //int c_radius = 200;

    //int first_point1 = (int)(Math.Cos(0) * c_radius + x);
    //int first_point2 = (int)(Math.Sin(0) * c_radius + y);

    //Point point = new Point(first_point1, first_point2);
    Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Red;
    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, x, y, 300, 300);
    pictureBox1.Image = image.Image;
    p = p.next;
  }
}
```

I have tried modifying the code in a number of ways but in the end I just reverted it back to what I thought was most direct.

Comment: It's not clear if the circles aren't appearing, or are they appearing in the wrong place.  Picture would help here to understand the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech They aren't appearing at all. I've tried dramatically large circles which should cover the entire image but nothing shows.

Comment: Are you debugging it?  What are the values of `x` and `y`?  You should be disposing that `Graphics g` because you created it.

Comment: That `Points` class needs to be documented, too.  It looks suspicious.  Why would `p.next` product a null `p`?  That looks like it should be a simple `for-each` loop there, not a `while...`

Comment: @LarsTech `Points` could be a linked list, for some reason?